# laptop shutdown freeze Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: freeze

Gigabyte sabre 15 laptop freezes at Ubuntu 17.10 progress bar (red & white dots) when shutdown or restart from the desktop menu. Also tried REISOU with ctrl & print screen, but still freezes. Is this a bios update problem ? Grub2 bootloader file ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing the proprietary drivers for Nvidia? I did and my system has had fewer kinks since then, including the ability to shutdown.

To check to see if this works:

- Go to **System Settings > Additional Drivers**
- Look for the Nvidia driver that is inactive and click <kbd>Activate</kbd> and it will be downloaded and installed
- Force shutdown and reboot

and it should be fixed!